# PHP Query string for templating using if and isset()

Tags: php, templates, request, isset

I'm currently organising my site by forcing everything through index.php using .htaccess. Then I'm including some logic that uses the `$REQUEST_URI` to display the relevant template (see the code). My problem is that I find it annoying to have to check the the request array value is set every single time, eg `if (isset($request[1])&&$request[1]=="projects"){...`

Is there a way that I can just write `if ($request[1]=="projects"){...`

The above line, throws an error if `$request[1]` is not set, ie on the home page.

Here's my complete code. It shows an individual project on mydomain.com/projects/house,
and it shows a list of projects on mydomain.com/projects

```
$request = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (isset($request[1])&&$request[1]=="projects"){

    require("./controller/projects.php");

    if (isset($request[2])){
        include("./view/project.html");
    } else {
        include("./view/project-list.html");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to force everything through index.php... surely there is a better use of .htaccess to achieve what you want to achieve?  I think we need more details as to why you are implementing this?

Comment: @Coulton I believe this is how Wordpress operates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function!

```
function current_controller() {
    if(isset($request[1])
        return $request[1];
}

if(current_controller() === "projects") { ... }
```

Or you can do

```
function is_current_controller($controller) {
    if(isset($request[1])&&$request[1] === $controller)
        return true;
    return false;
}

if(is_current_controller("projects") { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not ditch the else/elseif method as use `swtich()`?

Like this

```
$request = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$check = $request[];

switch($check) {
 case "1";
   include (folder/file1.php);
   break;
 case "2";
   include (folder/file2.php);
   break;     
 case "3";
   include (folder/file3.php);
   break;
```

}